# Implicit conversion for function subtyping

Tags: functions, type-systems, type-casting, type-conversion, subtypes

Languages with coercions (*i.e.* [implicit type conversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion)) allows expressing things like that (irrespective of any syntax):

```
f : int32 → int32 = λx.x+x
a : int16 = 42
b : int64 = f(a)
```

Where type conversions are not explicitly indicated in the code. Type checking relies on: `int16 <: int32 <: int64`. Is there a programming language where this extends to [subtyping of function types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Function_types)? Allowing to write:

```
g : int16 → int64 = f
```

Answer (score 2):

You are conflating coercions with subtyping.

- Some coercions like upcasting are free and are connected with subtyping. They only have an effect during type checking, and they have the same runtime representation. E.g. all objects might have the same representation (a pointer).

  E.g. in Java, a method `Derived f(Base x)` is a subtype of `Base g(Derived x)` if `Derived` is a subtype of `Base`.
- Other coercions are implicit conversions that have some runtime effect, e.g. converting an int to a double. Not only may you have to emit code for that, but the types may have a different representation (e.g. byte vs. word). If the data needs to be changed, the ABI of two functions is not compatible.

  E.g. in Java, a function `int f(double x)` is not a subtype of `double g(int x)` as the function signatures are fundamentally different – primitive types like int are not objects that have any subtyping relationship, but value types.

  In some cases, `f` and `g` might be source-compatible: `double y = f(42)` can also use `g` in Java. But depending on the function that is called, different code will be generated at the call site. The caller and not the function performs the conversion of these values.

  C++ templates are a bit unusual because they essentially perform macro-like code generation. So it would be possible to write a C++ template function `t` that could deal with `f` or `g` as long as those functions are source-compatible. But `t(f)` and `t(g)` call entirely different functions `t<...>(...)` as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: (arguably, this answer conflates subtyping with ABI compatibility. But those are related: a type system tries to describe what can be done safely, and a function can only be substituted safely if it has a compatible ABI)